# How to find objects inside nested array of objects using lodash?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have this data set

```
var records = [{
    gc: '2',
    time: 1231232423,
    cards: [{
        cardCode: '12121',
        rssi: 23
      }, {
        cardCode: '12122',
        rssi: 33
      }, {
        cardCode: '12421',
        rssi: 43
      }

    ]
  },
  {
    gc: '3',
    time: 4331232233,
    cards: [{
        cardCode: '6423',
        rssi: 23
      }, {
        cardCode: '12421',
        rssi: 13
      }

    ]
  }, , {
    gc: '4',
    time: 4331232233,
    cards: [{
        cardCode: '8524',
        rssi: 03
      },
      {
        cardCode: '6423',
        rssi: 23
      }, {
        cardCode: '12421',
        rssi: 67
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I have an array`(records)` of objects and in each object there is an another array`(cards)`. This means if i will always have `cards` array inside an object present in 'records'. So from very first i want to iterate over whole list `records` and compare the cards array of all objects with each other and then find the matched object's `rssi` value and push the object(that have minimum rssi value ) into another new array. In the same way at the end i want the array in which i have all the matching objects which have minimum rssi value. I am using `lodash` and have tried this

```
 matchedRecords =   records.forEach(record=>{
 record.cards.forEach(record=>{
  _.filter(records, _.flow(
    _.property('cards'),
     _.partialRight(_.some, { cardCode: record.cardCode })
         ));
      })
   })
```

My desired result would be

```
 [
   {
    gc : 3, 
    cards : [{
     cardCode : '12421',
     rssi : 13
    }]
   }
 ]
```

Note : **cards array object should be compare on the bassis of `cardCode key`**

Comment: The `cardCode: '8524'` should have an rssi of 30? If it's 3 it should be the minimum.

Comment: No i have to iterate through whole `records` array and find matching cards inside each cards array and find the object which has minimum rssi. In my above mentioned data set the object which have `cardCode ` equal to `12421` is present in all three objects of `records` so code should be return the object which has minimum rssi value

Comment: Do you know there will be only one matching card?  If not, where does `gc: 3` come from in the result?  The lowest `rssi` for one cardCode might be in a different record than the lowest rssi for another one.

Comment: no i don't know that what matching cards would be because cards array will be dynamic in each object of `records`

Comment: So, then, where does the `gc: 3` come from in your output?

Comment: because code should compare and get matching records first so in my given data set only one object with `cardCode` : '12421' is there. Basically i want to match records on the basis of `cardCode` and you can see that object with `12421` is present in all three objects inside `records` and by comparing each object's rssi there is the minimum rssi of 13 with `cardCode : 12421`

Comment: But now add card `{cardCode: '6423', rssi: 13}` to your first record.  We now have two cards which match all three records, but one has lowest rssi in record `gc: 2` and the other has it in record `gc: 3`.  That's why I'm confused. It's straightforward how to get the cards, but there's more to do.

Comment: @ScottSauyet so code should return an array having this result 
result = [{gc : 3,  cards : [{  cardCode : '12421', ssi : 13 }]
         }, {gc : 2, cards : [{cardCode : 6423, rssi : 13}]}]

Comment: But what would be the `gc` value in this case?  The array of cards I can do.

Comment: @ScottSauyet don't confuse please. Code should match one by one. Like pick one card from cards array of record's one object and then search for that object's card code into each record's object card code and then it should push each object which is present in all records but push that object which has minimum rssi value

Comment: Not trying to confuse, trying to understand.  When I asked my last question, your prior comment ended after "having this result"... but I think that update makes it clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Lodash

```js
let records = [{"gc":"2","time":1231232423,"cards":[{"cardCode":"12121","rssi":23},{"cardCode":"12122","rssi":33},{"cardCode":"12421","rssi":43}]},{"gc":"3","time":4331232233,"cards":[{"cardCode":"6423","rssi":23},{"cardCode":"12421","rssi":13}]},{"gc":"4","time":4331232233,"cards":[{"cardCode":"8524","rssi":3},{"cardCode":"6423","rssi":23},{"cardCode":"12421","rssi":67}]}]

let mapped = _.reduce(records, (acc, rec) => {
  _.forEach(rec.cards, (card) => {  
    card = _.assign({}, card, { gc: rec.gc, multiple: false })
    
    if (card.cardCode in acc) {
      let lc = acc[card.cardCode].rssi < card.rssi
      acc[card.cardCode] =  lc ? acc[card.cardCode] : card
      acc[card.cardCode].multiple = lc
    } else {
      acc[card.cardCode] = card;
    }    
  })
  return acc
}, {})

let result = _.reduce(records, (acc, rec) => {
  rec.cards = _.filter(rec.cards, (card) => mapped[card.cardCode].multiple && mapped[card.cardCode].gc === rec.gc )
  rec.cards.length && acc.push(rec)
  return acc
}, []);

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100%!important
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Updated

This version is based on the understanding reached after the long requirements discussion in the comments to the question.  It does not use lodash.  It's gotten complex enough that it probably should break into smaller pieces, and lodash might help with that.

It includes not just `gc`, but also `time` from the original records, and will, in fact, include anything else from there.  If you want just `gc`, simply remove `...rest` from the code.

```js
const sharedCards = records => 
  Object.values(
    Object .entries (records .reduce (
      (a, {cards, ...rest}) => cards .reduce (
        (a, {cardCode, rssi}) => ({
          ...a, 
          [cardCode]: [...(a[cardCode] || []), {...rest, rssi}]
        }),
        a,
      ), 
      {}
    ))
    .filter ( ([code, rs]) => rs.length == records.length )
    .reduce((a, [code, rs]) => {
      const {gc, rssi, ...rest} = rs.reduce(
        (r1, r2) => r2.rssi < r1.rssi ?  r2 : r1, 
        {rssi: Infinity}
      )
      return {
        ...a, 
        [gc]: {
          ...(a[gc] || {...rest, gc}), 
          cards: [...((a[gc] || {gc}).cards || []), {cardCode: code, rssi}]
        }
      }
    }, {})  
  )
  
  
const records = [{gc: "2", time: 1231232423, cards: [{cardCode: "12121", rssi: 23}, {cardCode: "12122", rssi:33}, {cardCode: "12421", rssi: 43}]}, {gc: "3", time: 4331232233, cards: [{cardCode: "6423", rssi: 23}, {cardCode: "12421", rssi: 13}]}, {gc: "4", time: 4331232233, cards: [{cardCode: "8524", rssi: 3}, {cardCode: "6423", rssi: 23}, {cardCode: "12421", rssi: 67}]}];

console .log (
  sharedCards (records)
)

// Now we add `{cardCode: "6423", rssi: 7}` to the first record
const records2 = [{gc: "2", time: 1231232423, cards: [{cardCode: "6423", rssi: 7}, {cardCode: "12121", rssi: 23}, {cardCode: "12122", rssi:33}, {cardCode: "12421", rssi: 43}]}, {gc: "3", time: 4331232233, cards: [{cardCode: "6423", rssi: 23}, {cardCode: "12421", rssi: 13}]}, {gc: "4", time: 4331232233, cards: [{cardCode: "8524", rssi: 3}, {cardCode: "6423", rssi: 23}, {cardCode: "12421", rssi: 67}]}];

console .log (
  sharedCards (records2)
)
```

### Original Answer

This is only a partial solution, to be updated if we can resolve the discussion in the comments.  It fetches all the cards which appear in every record, and chooses the version with the lowest rssi.  This may be close to the requirements, or it may not.

It doesn't use lodash.  It might simplify a bit with lodash, but probably not very much.

```js
const sharedCards = records => 
  Object .entries (records .reduce (
    (a, {cards}) => cards .reduce (
      (a, {cardCode, rssi}) => ({...a, [cardCode]: [...(a[cardCode] || []), rssi]}),
      a,
    ), 
    {}
  ))
  .filter ( ([code, rssis]) => rssis.length == records.length )
  .map ( ([code, rssis]) => ({ cardCode: code, rssi: Math .min (...rssis) }) )
    

const records = [{gc: "2", time: 1231232423, cards: [{cardCode: "12121", rssi: 23}, {cardCode: "12122", rssi:33}, {cardCode: "12421", rssi: 43}]}, {gc: "3", time: 4331232233, cards: [{cardCode: "6423", rssi: 23}, {cardCode: "12421", rssi: 13}]}, {gc: "4", time: 4331232233, cards: [{cardCode: "8524", rssi: 3}, {cardCode: "6423", rssi: 23}, {cardCode: "12421", rssi: 67}]}];

console .log (
  sharedCards (records)
)

// Now we add `{cardCode: "6423", rssi: 7}` to the first record
const records2 = [{gc: "2", time: 1231232423, cards: [{cardCode: "6423", rssi: 7}, {cardCode: "12121", rssi: 23}, {cardCode: "12122", rssi:33}, {cardCode: "12421", rssi: 43}]}, {gc: "3", time: 4331232233, cards: [{cardCode: "6423", rssi: 23}, {cardCode: "12421", rssi: 13}]}, {gc: "4", time: 4331232233, cards: [{cardCode: "8524", rssi: 3}, {cardCode: "6423", rssi: 23}, {cardCode: "12421", rssi: 67}]}];

console .log (
  sharedCards (records2)
)
```

Comment: Your solution is working perfectly but it can't giving gc inside result's each object. Result should look like  this in first case 
  [{"gc" : "3", cards : [{
    "cardCode": "12421",
    "rssi": 13
  }]
}

And in second case result should be
[{
 "gc" :  "2",
   "cards" : [
        {
    "cardCode": "6423",
    "rssi": 7
  }]
},
{
 "gc" : "3",
  "cards" : [
 {
    "cardCode": "12421",
    "rssi": 13
  }]
  }
]

Comment: @FahadHassanSubzwari: I wrote the version you saw before getting the full requirements.  I even mentioned that in the text above.  Since getting those requirements, I updated to the version that's now here.